# What’s a possible one-word replacement for “applicable in every situation”?

Tags: single-word-requests

I just want to ask what word can be put in replacement to the bolded phrase in: “This formula is not **applicable in every situation** and may vary.”

Comment: ubiquiplicable would be a fun word...

Comment: None of the answers sound natural to me in this context. Why do you need a single word for this?

Comment: If there was a single word for [YMMV](https://www.google.com/search?q=YMMV&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b) why would we need an abbreviation?

Comment: If the Urban Dictionary would count as a credible source, omnipropriate would be a possible answer :')

Comment: As a suggestion, when I first read your statement, the bolded part stood out. I thought you were asking for a word that meant "applicable in every situation" (the exact opposite of what you were looking for!) Consider bolding the "not" as well.

Comment: I'm into the whole brevity thing, so I'd say "This formula may vary."

Comment: Are you looking for a single word replacement that would be applicable in ***every*** situation? =)

Comment: "all-around" sort of feels like cheating a bit, but that would work, not as fun of a word though

Answer (score 167, accepted):

## [Universal](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/universal)

> adapted or adjustable to meet varied requirements (as of use, shape,
>   or size)
>
> - a universal gear cutter
> - universal remote control

Comment: For the specific usage in the question, I'd favor the two-word phrase "universally applicable", but if a single word is absolutely required, "universal" may be best.

Comment: @supercat. Sure. Or why not universally universal?

Comment: @Ares: The phrase "universally universal" would be two words.  If a two-word phrase is acceptable, the phrase "universally applicable" better describes what particular quality of the thing is universal.  If a two-word phrase isn't acceptable, the phrase "universally universal" would  be unacceptable for that reason alone.

Comment: @supercat. It was a joke.

Answer (score 26):

[**General**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/general), especially in mathematics:

> involving, relating to, or applicable to every member of a class, kind, or group
>
> the *general* equation of a straight line

One option you have is to say what the equation is rather than what it isn’t, such as: “This equation applies only to a special case.”

Comment: The phrase "without loss of generality" comes to mind

Comment: @JollyJoker That’s related, yes. You know this, but given which site this is, here’s a recent example of usage from Mathematics.SX: “Let us call the endpoints of the interval, *a* and *b*. Without loss of generality, let *a* < *b*.” That is, since we’re making up arbitrary names for the endpoints, we can call the lower endpoint *a* and the higher endpoint *b* and still have a fully general description of the endpoints of any interval (that isn’t degenerate).

Answer (score 24):

This would also fit nicely:

> **Generic**
>  shared by, typical of, or relating to a whole group of similar things, rather than to any particular thing:

Source: [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/generic)

Comment: Generic would be a bad fit here, because it's possible to have a generic formula good for, say, 99% of situations, but still have a few exceptions preventing it from being universal.

Answer (score 17):

## [All-purpose](https://www.wordnik.com/words/all-purpose)

> *from The American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, 4th Edition*
>
> ***adj.*** Having many purposes or uses: an all-purpose thread.
>
> *from Wiktionary, Creative Commons Attribution/Share-Alike License*
>
> ***adj.*** for all purposes; general-purpose
>
> *from the GNU version of the Collaborative International Dictionary of English*
>
> ***adj.*** not limited in use or function.
>
> *from WordNet 3.0 Copyright 2006 by Princeton University.*
>
> ***adj.*** not limited in use or function

Answer (score 9):

Depending on the context (does the formula solve problems? And if so, do you want to make it clear that it doesn't solve them all?) you may use:

**panacea**

> 1. something that will solve all problems:
>
> *Technology is not a panacea for all our problems.*
>
> 2. something that will cure all illnesses
>
> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/panacea)

Comment: Unfortunately, that would require a two-word replacement:  *a* panacea, and therefore doesn't answer the question.

Comment: We need an adjective - panaceaic?? Which probably didn't exist - till now! However, it's more applicable to cure than 'fits all'.

Answer (score 9):

### Comprehensive

> complete; including all or nearly all elements or aspects of something.
> — [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/comprehensive)

Answer (score 6):

**All-encompassing**, according to [Merriam Webster Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/all-encompassing):

> including everything or everyone

Their example sentence:

> We're unlikely to find an all-encompassing solution.

Attribution: "All-encompassing." Merriam-Webster.com. Accessed June 14, 2018. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/all-encompassing.

Answer (score 4):

While Universal is probably the best answer I would like to add in to the mix **Ubiquitous** as in globally applicable or present.

Comment: But it doesn't mean "globally applicable".

Comment: Specifically, it means "globally present", regardless of applicability. Many, many, things are ubiquitous only because of inappropriate application.

Answer (score 3):

## [Versatile](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/versatile#English)

> **versatile** (comparative more versatile, superlative most versatile)
>
> - Capable of doing many things competently.
> - Having varied uses or many functions.
> - Changeable or inconstant.

Comment: Hmmm, the made up word **"universatile"** would be a nice fit.  :)

Answer (score 3):

## [Silver Bullet](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/silver%20bullet)

> : something that acts as a magical weapon; especially : one that instantly solves a long-standing problem

To say that something "isn't a silver bullet" is to say it's not going to magically solve the problem, like a "universal formula" would

Answer (score 1):

Two words to indicate that something can work in multiple (though perhaps not all) cases are:

**Multipurpose**, according to [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/multipurpose):

> A multipurpose tool, etc. can be used in several different ways

(Definition of “multipurpose” from the Cambridge Advanced Learner's Dictionary & Thesaurus © Cambridge University Press)

Or **multifunctional**, according to [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/multifunctional):

> having several different uses

(Definition of “multifunctional” from the Cambridge Advanced Learner's Dictionary & Thesaurus © Cambridge University Press)

Answer (score 1):

## Swiss army-

This is much more colloquial, but since swiss army knives have many tools for multiple functions, up to [Wenger Giant's 141 functions from 87 implements](https://partsolutions.com/engineering-the-worlds-largest-swiss-army-knife-the-1300-wenger-giant/)!

So you could say,

> This isn't a "swiss army-function to fix everything."

Answer (score 1):

Standardized/Standard, or ubiquitous.

Comment: Please provide dictionary references and definitions to explain your answer. Otherwise they'll likely be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

I can't believe no one has mentioned:

**Ubiquitous**

> Definition: present, appearing, or found everywhere.
> — [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/ubiquitous)

Comment: Actually, you’re the third.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought was the already mentioned *Universal*, but a more obscure word could be:

> ## [Omnirelevant](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/omnirelevant#English)
>
> Relevant everywhere, or to everything; always relevant.

Further thought evoked the memory of another candidate, albeit more for situations where the omnirelevant object has been intentionally altered to become:

> ## [Omnified](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/omnify)
>
> [Rendered] universal [by design or modification].

Comment: Why is a more obscure word preferable?

Comment: I made no mention as to its preferability, I only wished to make its availability known, despite its obscurity :). Why the _asker_ found it preferable I can only guess at; possibly it fit the tone of his work better. I would also posit that despite being little used, the meaning of `omnirelevant` can be readily deduced by most speakers of the language, as it is composed of a relatively common prefix with an established meaning and a common word. Therefore, the usual reason for avoiding obscure words is voided, and more freedom is afforded to the author.

Comment: OK, the way you wrote it seemed like you were proposing it because it's more obscure. I think the OP's approach of negating a word like this is misguided ("not omnirelevant" seems awkward), and perhaps he should be looking for a word that expresses the negative concept by itself. But that's not your problem.

Comment: `Not omnirelevant` would be the Latin way, for instance `Non omniaptus`, but perhaps English should have had a word like `aliquirelevant`: `Relevant to some`. This would have formed the sentence `This formula is aliquirelevant and may vary`, avoiding the possibly awkward negation. How would you suggest I convey my meaning more clearly? I did not wish it to seem like I was proposing it for that reason.

Comment: Now *that's* obscure :)

Answer (score 0):

Just to add another option which fits the definition nicely:

> ## [Pervasive](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pervasive)
>
> Existing in or spreading through every part of something.

Comment: This means it is present in every situation, but not that it is helpful/useful in every situation.

Answer (score 0):

It's funny, because I was just reading a very different post in another group when I see the word ***irréfragable*** (in French, which is ***irrefragable*** in English), and depending on my (lots of) dictionnaries, I believe it is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I might suggest “flexible,” but the sentence structure makes the overall meaning unclear out of context. With “...and may vary” are you further illustrating *why* the formula is not always applicable? Or are you providing a second, *independent* reason for caution? In other words, are you saying the formula isn't aways appropriate, and at least one reason is that it may vary? Or is the possibility that it may vary a separate issue? It's not discernable from the sentence alone, and it may have an impact on which term would best address your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

**Situational**

This formula is situational and may vary.

Answer (score -7):

As a non-native speaker, I thought of **passe-partout**, according to [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/passe-partout):

> that which passes or allows passage everywhere

The problem is that you want a positive word and put "not" in front of it, while you can use a negative term as well. 
That wouldn't be "pas passe-partout", which would sound funny, especially in French. But more something like **inapplicable** or **non-applicable**.

Attribution: Webster’s New World College Dictionary, 4th Edition. Copyright © 2010 by Houghton Mifflin Harcourt. All rights reserved.

Comment: Hearing or reading *passe-partout* I would immediately think of a character in Verne's *Around the World in Eighty Days*, but apparently it has other meanings such as a pass-key, or part of a picture frame, or a two-man saw.  I am not sure the correct meaning would be understood here

Comment: Native speaker here. I have *never* heard anything even close to passe-partout, and have no idea what it means. If you use this word, you're going to confuse a lot of people.

Comment: While this isn't commonly used in English, it seems like a good answer to me. Having said that, the 9 down votes are somewhat over the top..

Comment: @LastStar007 Aaaaaaand that is why I said NON native speaker, something which you and apparently nine others completely missed. But totally. Or there's something decidedly sexist going on here. Saying this will likely invite even more sexist downvotes, but then again, this is a boy-site. Perhaps even of that **awkward, can't get-a-date** variety? The number of downvotes will tell us.

Comment: @GwenKillerby I assure you, no sexism was involved on my part. I didn't even notice your username or profile pic until you mentioned it. And I did notice that you said you were a non-native speaker--I commented to say that "passe-partout" may be understood in some circles, but native AmE speakers are not one of those circles.

Comment: @GwenKillerby: You posted a (hyphenated) word that *looks* French, is in the bottom 20% of English words (according to [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/passe-partout)), and where you have to contort the definition to get it to match the question. What are you thinking: that being a non-native speaker *entitles* you to post an answer like that? That men shouldn’t be allowed to vote against a women (for any reason, ever)? … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  I concur that the (now) 12 downvotes are excessive, but the 5 upvotes seem undeserved, too.   We might wonder how many of them were motivated by personal reasons (such as pity or sexism), but accusing people of malicious motives that you can’t prove [isn’t nice](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) either.

Comment: @Scott nope. I was thinking that this was a useful addition to the other answers, which it was, since it fits and is relatively unknown. Now I'm thinking that YOU have entitlement issues in others, because [1] bringing up entitlement issues as a majority group member indicates fake victimhood. [2] I'm **knowing** that asking sneering questions like "That men shouldn’t be allowed to vote against a women (for any reason, ever)?" constitutes sexism, since it questions the very existence of sexism and disses women bringing it up. So, would you mind stopping badgering me? Thanks.

Comment: @Scott as to your second post  "but accusing people of malicious motives that you can’t prove isn’t nice". Well, I suppose you're right. Because similarly, accusing men of rape is just as bad as getting raped, I guess. To transfer: getting downvotes has real consequences. Your " accussing malicious motives" hasn't. Hint: you're using False Equivalence. Also: Can't prove? Sexism is rampant, ESPECIALLY online. Your reaction proves it: You assume "entitlement" for no good reason. Since you don't have my experience, don't talk about it. Post as a woman sometime (pretty or plain). Enjoy!

Comment: @GwenKillerby - I would downvote because this is the English Language forum and _that phrase is not common to the English Language_ (the fact it's French doesn't bother me, though).  Also, I'm female and exp programmer. I've never personally experienced anything sexist on the SE sites. Only reason I know you're female is because you keep arguing about it and then comparing downvotes to rape in terms of "real consequences".....? Please don't attack the users here; they've helped me out for years