# Adjective similar to "in-depth" or "slow-paced"

Tags: phrases, adjectives, questions, adjectival-phrases

I need to know whether there's an adjective that could work in this sentence:

> I will provide ___ help so you can solve problems independently.

I hope that the answer could be similar to "in-depth" or "slow-paced".

Comment: Don't you want *minimal* rather than deep or slow? Independence comes from getting just enough support to learn from and take it yourself next time.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want the word to mean. (Maybe [What’s a possible one-word replacement for “applicable in every situation”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/450072/191178)?)

Comment: Yes, "in-depth" works there.  Note, you're supposed to check a dictionary, and explain to us where you got stuck in trying to figure this out yourself.  Also, I hope you'll take a look at our sister site, English Language Learners.  Maybe it would be useful for you.

Comment: You need to explain the context. It only makes sense if you're saying "I'll teach you how to solve problems like this so that in future you can solve problems independently" rather than "I'll provide a lot of help so you can solve these problems without any help".

Comment: In-depth and slow-paced imply different things.  Maybe it's likely that something in-depth will also be slow-paced as a consequence, but that's more of a side effect. Anyway, I recommend you check a thesaurus with synonyms for these things, and see if one of them works. E.g. meticulous, comprehensive, exhaustive.

Comment: Based on your sentence itself ("so you can solve problems independently"), I would try to fill in the blank with "enough", "ample", "sufficient" and see if that gives the meaning you want.